# Division resulting to '0' in bash, but values of numerator and denominator should led to different result

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to find the average CPU utilization of my android application using the code below

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
while [ $counter -le 10 ]
    do
        current_cpu=$(adb shell top -n 1 | grep org.carleton.iot.mobile_cep | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's|%||g')
        echo "current_cpu = "$current_cpu
        total_cpu=$((total_cpu + current_cpu))
        echo "total_cpu = "$total_cpu
        echo "counter = "$counter
        average_cpu=$(((totalMemory / counter)))
        echo "average_cpu = "$average_cpu
        echo "\n"
        ((counter++))

        sleep 1
    done
echo  done
```

It gives the following results

```
current_cpu = 7
total_cpu = 7
counter = 1
average_cpu = 0

current_cpu = 8
total_cpu = 15
counter = 2
average_cpu = 0


current_cpu = 6
total_cpu = 21
counter = 3
average_cpu = 0

current_cpu = 8
total_cpu = 29
counter = 4
average_cpu = 0
```

However, the value of average_cpu should be equal to `total_cpu/counter` value.

Comment: It's a simple typo: `$(((totalMemory / counter)))` is zero because `totalMemory` is not set. (You meant to write `total_cpu` instead.) That said, you should follow Andrea Corbellini's link to learn about better approaches.

Comment: @ruakh : omg, my bad. you are right boss 

Comment: And `bc <<< 'scale=2; total_cpu/counter'` does not work because you forgot to expand the variables: `bc <<< "scale=2; $total_cpu/$counter"`

Comment: Just for kicks, `echo "totalMemory: $totalMemory"` before `average_cpu=$(((totalMemory / counter)))` to verify it actually contains what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

Bash division don't work when result is not integer, you have use scale and bc as

```
echo "scale=2 ; $totalmemory / $counter" | bc
```

Here value of scale is the precision like if it's 2, it'll return values upto 2 places after decimal point like .55

Comment: Or `bc -l <<< "scale=2 ; $totalmemory / $counter"` (avoids creating an extra process)

Comment: -1, sorry. Division works just fine: it rounds down, but it doesn't randomly give zero when the correct answer is greater than 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly give zero"

Comment: @crack_iT: What I mean is, read the question. Surely you don't believe that `29 / 4` rounds all the way to zero?